# Failed screenshot in Mochawesome Report in case of Test Retry

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, mochawesome

I am using `addContext()` that mocha provides to append failure screenshots in the Mochawesome html report. I have written this under `support/index.js`

```
Cypress.on('test:after:run', (test, runnable) => {
  if (test.state === 'failed') {
    const screenshot = `FailureScreenshots/${Cypress.spec.name
      }/${runnable.parent.title} -- ${test.title} (failed).png`;
    addContext({ test }, screenshot);
  }
});
```

This works perfectly when there is a failure(and there are no Test Retries) it just appends the failure screenshot in the html report bases on `test.state`. However, in case of Test Retries, where on the first run the test failed but on the second run the test passed, it still attaches the failure screenshot. How can I prevent that? It should only append the screenshot when the test finally fails after the number of retries have been exhausted.

Comment: Have you tried checking the number of retries before taking the screenshot: cy.state('runnable')._retries

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Use `test.currentRetry === test.retries` in the if condition.